# Obtaining Solaris Device path

Tags: solaris, device-driver

I am working on Solaris 12 and I am trying to get device path like this:

```
/pci@0,0/pci108e,4856@1f,2:devctl
```

I could obtain the this path through CLI using prtconf -v. How could I obtain the path through api using C function? I tried serveral functions in libdevinfo, such as di_devfs_path, but it didn't give the same path as the prtconf gives me. Should I use functions like di_node_name, di_instance, di_binding_name to get pieces of information and construct the path by my own. Or there is a function to get the whole device path?

Thanks.

Comment: "Solaris 12" ? Double check ...

Comment: What's the solution if it's solaris 10 or 11?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, unless you're working for Oracle in the Systems division, you're *not* working on Solaris 12. (If you *are* working for Oracle, why haven't you asked
Oracle internal mailing lists for help?)

Secondly, the `:devctl` node is a minor for the device, so you'll need to walk the minor nodes using `di_walk_minor()` and check `di_minor_name()` to see if it matches your criteria.

Finally, yes, this should work on Solaris 10 and later.